# cairo-infinality : conflict between mesa-libgl and nvidia-libgl

Tags: arch-linux

I'm trying to enhance the font rendering on my Arch and it turns out that when I install `cairo-infinality` using yaourt it complains about a conflict between mesa and nvidia libgl :

> :: mesa-libgl and nvidia-libgl are in conflict (libgl). Remove nvidia-libgl? [y/N]

I tried to edit the pkgfile to replace mesa with nvidia but during the build I get :

> no gl.pc nor openGL headers found. configure error : openGL surface backend feature could not be enabled.

Is there something to be done in your opinion ?

Comment: `cairo-infinality` only depends on `libgl`, which is provided by `nvidia-libgl`, so yaourt should not try to install `mesa-libgl`.

Comment: @Wieland That's not true. [Here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cairo-infinality/) you see that it depends on ``libgl`` which is provided by ``nvidia-libgl`` **and** ``mesa-libgl``.

Comment: Sorry; my above comment is a little confusing. It is provided by ``nvidia-libgl``, *and also depends separately* on ``mesa-libgl``.